# Clickhouse optimize Join query by memory

Tags: clickhouse

This request runs out of memory. The limit is 10 GB.
The calls table size is 100 GB, but the daily data size is no more than 1 GB.
Let's size the temp_calls tables - 20 GB.
It seems to me that he should execute the first subquery and get a table weighing ~1 GB, then join it with the second table and as a result get a table weighing ~1.1 GB. However, for some reason it doesn't work that way.

```
INSERT INTO new_calls_with_new_column FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM calls WHERE create_date >= '2023-09-07 00:00:00' AND create_date < '2023-09-08 00:00:00') a
    left join
    (SELECT id, new_column FROM temp_calls) b USING id
```

Comment: Replace join with UNION ALL + GroupBY or try https://gist.github.com/den-crane/0c67d37d9ee4fb3e3251ef27cb8a8d4b `select .... from A join B .... settings join_algorithm = 'grace_hash', grace_hash_join_initial_buckets=8, grace_hash_join_max_buckets=8`;

Answer (score 0):

If `temp_calls` is 20GB and you only have 10GB of memory, then you will have memory issues.

This will not be the fastest way to do this, but try using the `grace_hash` join algorithm, which spills to disk if you run out of memory:

```
INSERT INTO new_calls_with_new_column FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM calls WHERE create_date >= '2023-09-07 00:00:00' AND create_date < '2023-09-08 00:00:00') a
    left join
    (SELECT id, new_column FROM temp_calls) b USING id
SETTINGS join_algorithm = 'grace_hash'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use JOINS to solve your case. Try updating column in  `calls` table in-place with [`ALTER TABLE UPDATE`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/update) and [dictionaries](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries).

```sql
CREATE DICTIONARY temp_calls_dict
(
    id UInt64,
    new_column_source String
)
PRIMARY KEY id
SOURCE(CLICKHOUSE(TABLE 'temp_calls'))
LAYOUT(HASHED())
LIFETIME(MIN 0 MAX 100);
```

```
ALTER TABLE calls ADD COLUMN new_column String;

ALTER TABLE calls UPDATE new_column=dictGet('temp_calls_dict', 'new_column_source', id)
WHERE create_date >= '2023-09-07 00:00:00' AND create_date < '2023-09-08 00:00:00');
```

You will get your `new_column` updated in place after mutation will finish. You can track progress in system.mutations table. This operation is much faster and requires much less memory. You can check other dictionaries layouts for example `cached` for your scenario.